# How to setup a HTTP caching proxy inside a NAT which is not a gateway?

Tags: networking, proxy, routing, nat, squid

I have the following setup of OSI level 2 and 3 devices in my IPv4-LAN with internet connection behind a NAT (all clients and servers are in `192.168.1.0/24`)

```
Internet
    |
Gateway (WiFi-"Router")/NAT
    |---------------------------------------------------------|
Switch                                                        |
    |--------------|-----------------------|                  |
Proxy client 1  Proxy client 2         Proxy server      untouchable
 (iptables)      (iptables)             (iptables)        client(s)
```

i.e. some machines which are supposed to work in the setup without any need to touch their network configuration (untouchable clients). `Proxy client N` and `Proxy server` run Linux and are fully configurable (e.g. with `iptables`).

I'd like to setup `Proxy server` and `Proxy client 1` so that every HTTP request `Proxy client 1` makes is done via `Proxy server` where previously fetched requests are cached and eventually served to avoid fetching from the internet. All device except the gateway have one NIC only.

What I tried (for `Proxy client 1` in order to make it work one day for more clients as well):

- setting up a NAT on `Proxy Server` using `fwbuilder` and it's redirection facilities as described in the [fwbuilder user guide](http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide5/redirection_rules.shtml) redirecting everything from `192.168.1.0/24` on port 80 to `Proxy server` on port 3128 where a `squid` 3.5.3 instance with `http_port transparent` directive set up is listening.
- setup the default route of `Proxy client 1` to be `Proxy server` and configured a virtual interface based on the only physical interface of `Proxy server`.
- figure out whether the ["DNAT to the same network" in the fwbuilder user guide](http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide5/dnat_to_same_network.shtml) applies to my case, but as far as I understand it's designed NATs setup on the gateway.

The `squid` logs don't show any activity.

If there's a way to create such a setup with another software than `squid` more easy, I'd be happy about suggestions.

Using application settings or environment variables which are picked up by applications iff they implement proxying aren't an option because 1000 applications require 1000 configurations in the worst case.

Comment: This sounds like it is correctly setup. Can you set your iptables rules that accomplish the transparent redirect of port 80 traffic to squid proxy on port 3128 to log action? Do you then see those rules being triggered? If they are, you should see traffic on the squid server if it's listening correctly. If they aren't, fix the rules.

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/dansguardian-content-filtering-with-transparent-proxy-on-ubuntu-9.10-karmic

Comment: The instructions at the link involve setting up firefox settings.

Comment: Can you please include the actual iptables rules that you are using?

Comment: I'm asking for the rules to be told to me in an answer.

Comment: It has you use firefox to test it. Then it has you remove the proxy from firefox. If you follow the very next step, you'll see it says everyone should be blocked after adding the iptables rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you're proxying HTTP requests, you don't need to setup NAT and set default gateway to the Proxy server on the clients. You only need to set the Proxy configurations on the clients.

Setup Squid as in [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/squid.html). In Windows client environments, proxy settings are typically configured in the ‘Internet Options‘ for Internet Explorer. Other applications can also use this information. Some have their own settings to configure.

Comment: Using the application settings is always an option which always works, but I don't consider it a network configuration (1000 applications require 1000 configurations in the worst case and errornous implementations cause trouble). I need a client firewall configuration for all HTTP traffic in order to stay sane.